# How to prevent focus to the browser window on error when developing with Next.JS?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

When developing with Next.JS, if the app throws an exception, you're redirected to the browser window rendering the error overlay.

Can this behavior be changed?

It can get quite annoying sometimes if you're doing multi-files editing, you're typing something in the first file and saving it to go change the second file accordingly but you're already redirected to the browser showing you the error you know you just created and were about to fix…

I searched the web and the docs but had no luck.

Comment: I was just yelling like "if you let me, there won't be any error". it was really annoying but just now, I installed Ventura 13.5 (Safari 16.6) and it went away.

Comment: Yeah it's so annoying… I had Ventura for a bit and still had the issue, let's cross our fingers that the behavior you're having now will stick

Comment: it works like a charm with Google Chrome !